# how to enable disable menu item of main window from tab buton

Tags: wpf, forms, tabs, tabcontrol, menu-items

In WPF form application

Menu and MenuItems are located on Main Window form, by default i kept it disabled

then on tab open which is a login form

MainWindow and Login Tab are different form and Login form is opened in TabControl which is located in MainWindow

now i want that when i login from login form, on successful login Menu and MenuItems should be enabled.

screenshot for reference is attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtvU7.png)
please share code for the same

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your new Login Tab from the MainWindow you can pass the whole MainWindow control (this) as a parameter to the Login tab.

From there you will be able to make calls on item inside the MainWindow from your Login Tab.

```
tabPage1.Enabled = false; // this disables the controls on it
tabPage1.Visible = false; // this hides the controls on it.
```

In the code below is taken from two separate Windows, the first one is called MainWindow and it has a button which opens a new window which I've called Window1.

MainWindow Code:

```
private void ButtonNewPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 newWindow = new Window1(this);
        this.Hide();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

Window1 code, notice in the Window1 Constructor it takes a parameter of type MainWindow:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private MainWindow parent;

    public Window1(MainWindow parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    private void ButtonOldPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        parent.Show();
    }
}
```

*Edited to show passing an old Window to a new Window

Comment: can you please share code to pass MainWindow Control as parameter in main window and tab page where to place i actually confused at this poing

Comment: I've added an explanation of passing windows to my original post